# Setting Mod4 in awesome

Tags: debian, xmodmap, awesome, key-mapping

I'm trying to set up awesome. When I start it the <kbd>Mod4</kbd> (Windows) key is not working. So I tried to extent my `.Xmodmap`

```
clear Mod4
add Mod4 = Multi_key
```

When I run `xmodmap .Xmodmap` the <kbd>Mod4</kbd> works, but there is "some" left. If there is an open terminal and I press <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Ret</kbd> to open a new terminal the computer either beeps or on the old terminal there is some dead key (pressing a results in  å). I tried several `clear` rules in the `.Xmodmap`, but neither worked. How can I best enable the <kbd>Mod4</kbd> in awesome?

`xev` reports:

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 36080759, (-557,202), root:(187,223),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 36080859, (-557,202), root:(187,223),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: `xmodmap` should not be necessary here. What does `xev` report when you press `Mod4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [awesome FAQ](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ) provides an [answer](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_does_Mod4_.22swallow.22_succeeding_key_presses.3F):

> **Why does <kbd>Mod4</kbd> "swallow" succeeding key presses?**
>   On some systems xkb by default maps the left windows key to "Multi_key" (at least in us and de layouts). `Multi_key` is an xkb feature which may be used to access uncommon symbols by pressing `Multi_key` and then (consecutively) two "normal" keys. The solution is to remap your windows key to mod4 and remove the Multi_key mapping. This can be done by including "altwin(left_meta_win)" in the xkb keyboard description xkb_symbols line.

```
   #!/bin/bash
   xkbcomp - $DISPLAY<<EOF
   xkb_keymap {
   xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwertz)"};
   xkb_types     { include "complete"};
   xkb_compat    { include "complete"};
   xkb_symbols   { include "pc+de(nodeadkeys)+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+level3(ralt_switch)+altwin(left_meta_win)+capslock(escape)"    };
   xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)"};
   };
   EOF
```